# Can an analytic set admit such a foliation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, foliations, analytic-geometry

I confess to be not an expert of analytic geometry, but I have come across the following problem, for which I need an help from experts in this specific field.

I was wondering myself if it is possible to find a real analytic set $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$, of codimension $1$, which comes equipped with a foliation into analytic compact manifolds of codimension $2$, one of whose leaves is exactly the singular locus of $X$.
Or otherwise, why is such a configuration irrealizable?

If the answer could depend on $n$, then I have meet this question working with $n=4$.

Comment: Codimention $2$ where, in $X$ ?

Comment: all the codimensions are referred to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: What is a foliation on a singular space? I'm only aware of the definition of holomorphic/analytic singular foliations on *nonsingular* spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the cone $x^2+y^2=(z-1)^3$, foliated by circles $z$ constant. Or just take any curve in the plane and foliate by points.

Comment: Maybe you want even the singular locus to be codimension 2?

Comment: Yes, I am considering an analytic set $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$, of codimension $1$, whose singular locus has codimension $2$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and, in particular, for the punctual edit.

Comment: In which sense is the vertex a leaf of the foliation?

Comment: The foliation is a topological foliation, and is smooth away from the singular locus: map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x/r,y/r,z)$ where $r^2=x^2+y^2$ to smooth it out. That was just how I interpreted the question. I suppose there could be many notions of foliation of a singular space.